# JSON Object caching in Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app in which I want to implement some caching. After the user logs in, there are about 200 DB calls to build a JSON object of things to be shown to the user, before he sees the page. That is making the performance go down quite a lot in case multiple users log in simultaneously.

I thought of using Redis, Memcachier or something similar to cache the object, and use the cache object in subsequent requests ([something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486596/best-way-to-cache-a-response-in-sinatra)), but my teammates are not very keen on using third party services.

Is there something I can do on my own server to implement caching?

Comment: In the link you posted, the second answers says: Don't forget to mkdir cache!

Comment: 200 DB calls? Sounds like a DBA needs to get involved.

Comment: how is that possible with 200 DB calls.  Are you looping over a cursor and creating query for each loop? Cache service will not solve a bad design.

Comment: Changing the design is the long term plan, but we’re close to a release. And I recently got on to the project. You have no idea how I feel about the design!

Answer (score 0):

What about change your Sinatra app to Padrino, which is built on Sinatra.
I use its own cache module, it exactly fits what you want.
[link here](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/padrino-cache)
One of my project still runs on it, and its cache stores in Redis.